# Transparency for Triangle strip Object Opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, transparency, alpha-transparency

I want to change the transparency of an object drawn with glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

I have used the blending option, like

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE);
```

(I have tried with these options:  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE)
In all, i am getting the color changed when I change the Alpha value, but not getting transparent or semi transparent. 
On alpha = 255, getting bright color,, when alpha= 1 getting a black color, but not transparent. If I make alpha = 0, I am getting a complete transparent. Is there any way to give semi transparency? 
(If I give alpha in between 1 to 255, lets say a 100, I am getting a light shade color, but background object is still not viewable. Means, transparancy is not available) 
Will someone help ?

Here is my plotting APIs used:

```
    glUniformMatrix4fv(i32Location, 1, GL_FALSE, afIdentity);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the standard "over" operator blending you want to use:
`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` The alpha value of the drawn object then determines how much of the foreground is visible, i.e. the result of the blend operation is:

> result = new_value * alpha + existing_value * (1-alpha)

If you draw the transparent object before the background object, you'll need to modify the depth test in order to see objects behind the transparent object. You can do this disabling the depth test (`glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`) if you don't need depth testing for the transparent object, or by disabling depth writes (`glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);`) if you want depth testing for the transparent object but don't want it to occlude objects behind it.